# Multi-NIC client w/ isc-dhcp-server & dynamic bind9 recommended configuration

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

I have a properly installed and configured isc-dhcp-server & bind9 box that is correctly updating DNS records based on leases. This works well.

I understand how the isc-dhcp-server can be configured for multi-nic / multi-homed use cases, multiple subnet, etc. What I'm having difficulty with is the proper / recommended configuration for a known client node with reservations. Specifically, I have a laptop with an internal wireless nic as well as an ethernet connection. This laptop (`aio`) is configured properly so that when a tethered connection is detected the wifi is disabled to favor the eth0 connection.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have `aio`dynamically register this change in bind9 and pull a reserved IP during this switchover. I can't seem to make that happen gracefully as my attempts to configure 2 reservations with the same hostname albeit different macs in isc-dhcp-server fail.

So slightly restated, I'm trying for

```
Host: aio    
eth0: 192.168.1.1    uniqueMac1
wl0:  192.168.1.2    uniqueMac2
```

Any help or direction appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing was using MAC address cloning which on the most recent version of NetworkManager **(1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.3)**  works across wifi and eth0.

On the DHCP server I did find it necessary to disable conflict detection (from time to time) with
`update-conflict-detection false;`